# Router can see computer but computer can't connect to internet

Tags: router, firewall, adsl-router, fritzbox

Since I had to replace my old Fritzbox modem with a new 7340 I can't connect to the internet anymore. When I open the Home Network page, I see a list of devices. The pc that I want to useto is listed, has a green icon, and when I hover over that icon, I see "connected with fritzbox, not in internet".

When I disconnect the computer, the green icon disappears. However, I cannot connect to the internet from that PC. Besides that, I cannot ping to the PC from another computer on the local network.

That other computer (the one I'm typing this question on) can connect to the internet without problem.

How can I fix this to get it working? Before I had no problems and had port forwarding working for a long time.

== Update ==

I've deleted the computer from the device list on the router. I've restarted the computer, and now the computer has appeared again, but no green icon saying that it is connected to the router. On the computer (Ubuntu 11.04) I get the message that there is no network connection (eth0). So there is or has been a connection somehow, because the computer appeared again in the list, but it cannot be used or has disappeared.

Comment: Since your router has detected the computer my guess is that your computer is misconfigured somehow. Anyway it has nothing to do with port forwarding so I'm removing it as it only complicates the question at this stage.

Comment: Can you ping the router from the PC in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. The computer has two NICs, and I probably changed the cable to another NIC when I moved it. Setting it back solved the problem.